# how to use events in magento content editor in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i want to use this events when on click this event is perform 
use different against that image or any other thing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qpny.png)

Comment: formulate your question differently, please. this sentence doesn't make any sense